# Raspberry Pi config - read parameters from a seperate file

Tags: linux, command-line, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I have a raspberry pi configured to boot chromium full screen which works great.  However, I want my non-techy user to update the website by simply editing a file on the desktop.

/etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart:

```
    # Link to the settings file on the desktop
    source /home/pi/Desktop/websetup.config

    # start chromium
    @chromium --noerrdialogs --kiosk $website --incognito
```

I would like to have a setup file on the desktop which my user can update the website and overscanning etc without directly editing any config files above:

i.e.

websetup.config:

```
# Enter website to show
webbsite=https://newWebsite.com

# Overscanning on = 1, turn off = 0
overscan=0
```

I, however, can output $website from a .sh bash but I cannot work out how to pass the value $website to chromium as I cannot pass the actual value

Comment: Why do you use `:` to set the variables? Looking at [this](https://wiki.lxde.org/en/LXSession#autostart_configuration_file) I guess it's impossible.

Comment: oops, thats a typo.. updated it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, I have managed to work it out.  I created a script called run_chromium.sh:

```
##
## this file is referenced in: /etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart
##

## website to show
website=https://www.website.com

## 0=overscanning off, 1=on
overscanning=1
```

and I linked to this script in autostart:

```
/bin/bash /home/pi/Desktop/run_chromium.sh
```